# Get max row from column (ignoring other values)

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to obtain the max value from duplicated values from a table in MySQL, my schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE `extinguisher_revisions` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `revision_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `extinguisher_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL
)
```

For example this table from the schema above:

| id | revision_id | extinguisher_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 | 33 |
| 3 | 11 | 33 |
| 4 | 10 | 30 |
| 5 | 12 | 31 |
| 6 | 13 | 31 |

Is needed to select the max row of `revision_id` and remove the other minimum `revision_id` like:

| id | revision_id | extinguisher_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 11 | 33 |
| 4 | 10 | 30 |
| 6 | 13 | 31 |

Hope is understandable, thanks.

Comment: Hi, Sam. What do you want specifically? To "select" required rows, or to "delete" not required rows?

Comment: Just to select them.

Answer (score 2):

On MySQL 8+, use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY extinguisher_id
                                 ORDER BY revision_id DESC) rn
    FROM extinguisher_revisions
)

SELECT id, revision_id, extinguisher_id
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can try joining to a subquery which finds the max `revision_id` value for each `extinguisher_id`:

```sql
SELECT er1.id, er1.revision_id, er1.extinguisher_id
FROM extinguisher_revisions er1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT extinguisher_id, MAX(revision_id) AS max_revision_id
    FROM extinguisher_revisions
    GROUP BY extinguisher_id
) er2
    ON er2.extinguisher_id = er1.extinguisher_id AND
       er2.max_revision_id = er1.revision_id;
```